# What Java method takes an int and returns +1 or -1?

Tags: java

What Java method takes an `int` and returns +1 or -1? The criteria for this is whether or not the `int` is positive or negative. I looked through the documentation but I'm bad at reading it and I can't find it. I know I've seen it somewhere though.

Comment: What about 0, is it positive or negative?

Comment: @fortran: The prevailing `signum` answer takes care of that too.

Comment: @Chris and @Halo that's the point, the op wants +1 or -1 on any int, not zero...

Comment: +1 because I had no idea this method existed, though I'm not sure when I would ever use it...

Comment: you do realize that in the time it took you to read the doc, post this question, and wait for the answer, you could have written a function to do exactly what you needed and gone to lunch?

Comment: @steven. that's a good point.
I might need it again in the future though in whcih case this will be faster overall.

Comment: @David: only if you remember the name of the function later ;-)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`Integer.signum(int i)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int))

Comment: can you link me to the relevent documentation

Comment: thanks. 
i don't supsoe theres a version that will return 1 when 0 is entered? or do i have to create that myself?

Comment: someone below gave an implementation, I suppose it's true.. you can modify it your way

Answer (score 6):

`Math.signum(value)` will do the trick but since it returns float or double (according to parameter) you will have to cast it:

```
int sign = (int)Math.signum(value);
```

or:

```
Integer.signum(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly evaluating to -1 or 1, and cooler (probably more efficient too) than `n < 0 ? -1: 1`:

```
(n >> 31) | 1
```

In case you want to use it for `long` too:

```
(n >> 63) | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.signum(double i)`

Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument is less than zero.
Special Cases:

- If the argument is `NaN`, then the result is `NaN`.
- If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument.

Parameters:

- d - the floating-point value whose signum is to be returned

Returns: The signum function of the argument

Since: 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.signum(int i)`, but if you want a custom in-line bit of code:

`int ans = i < 0 ? -1 : 1;`

if you want 0 also:

`int ans = i == 0 ? 0 : (i < 0 ? -1 : 1);`

Comment: That should be `int ans` for both.

Comment: Don't do this--it's going to make someone pause and think--that's the last thing you want in the middle of analyzing some bug.  Make it an external method or break it out into an if (since the number is probably just input to an if statement anyway, it would be much clearer to simply say (if i<0) else if (i > 0) else...

Answer (score -2):

For fun:

```
return (i > 0) ? 1 : ( (i < 0) ? -1 : 0 );
```